# AWS EC2 Next JS server stop responding after some time

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache2, bitnami

I am running NextJS server on AWS EC2 instances. I use pm2 to manage my applications. The setup works pretty fine but the problem is after a few days the server stops responding with a 522 status code.

Once I restart the apache server with `/opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache` it starts responding again.

I has been happening a long time and I have no clue what makes it happen. Last it happened there was around 730MB of free memory available out of 966MB. And processors were almost idle.

Here is the `htop` output image.
[image of htop output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq91d.png)

here is  output from `cat /opt/bitnami/apache/logs/error_log`
I have replaced the domain name with example.com and IP address with ***
https://pastebin.mozilla.org/YatsOA3i

Thanks for your  time and help.

Comment: Can you add more logging to your application to record extra metrics or information? If it stops after a few days my guess would be a resource leak. Things like file handles, connections, memory, etc.

Comment: @shearn89 nextjs image has a known issue, the sharp library causing a memory leak. But as you can see from the ```htop`` output, there seems to be enough memory left.